# How to reenable USB ports after a program broke them all?

Tags: boot, bios, wireshark

I do not even know how to phrase this question but let me try.

I am currently experiencing [this bug](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-bugs/201511/msg00733.html). Installing WireShark (and USBPcap) has made it so none of my USB ports work. This means that I cannot log into Windows at all.

I have this computer dual booted with Ubuntu so I logged into that and tried to delete all of the WireShark and USBPcap folders and files in Program Files but still, no USB devices work during log in.

This is not a problem with the ports themselves as they work on my Linux partition, but something that USBPcap did.

Is there anyway I can disable this or do anything to get my USB functionality back. Unfortunately I can't find a PS/2 keyboard to use so I am wondering if there is some sort of way through the biopsy to disable anything that is causing this.

Comment: Can you hit F8 to enter "safe mode" to disable anything that way? Sounds like the USBPcap driver is being loaded after the main system drivers. You should be able to uninstall USBPcap (or mess with its settings) in safe mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this incredibly frustrating issue. This seems to be a [known problem](https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/issues/3) that despite having being reported as far back as 2013 hasn't been fixed yet. A couple of suggestions:

- Try restoring the registry (got this from the thread above). This was the one that worked for me because it was possible to do this from the console in the diagnostics mode. (For some reason USB didn't work even in Safe Mode.)
- Try accessing the computer remotely (as suggested [here](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/50248/usb-ports-not-functioning/50257)).

If you can't even boot to safe mode because you lack a recovery USB/disc and don't have a PS2 port (as was my case) and because the goddamn Windows 8 removed the option to boot in safe mode by pressing F8, a dirty trick that worked for me was forcing Windows to enter into diagnostics mode by preventing it to start completely three consecutive times (e.g., unplug the computer while Windows is loading).

Comment: Great answer.  Luckily my computer had a PS/2 port, which was how I fixed my problem.